# Having modules problems Dockerizng simple node app

Tags: node.js, docker, echo

Having some problems while trying to create my first node.js app , super new to JS..

Trying to dockerize the app , like so :

```
docker build -t echo_app .
docker run -p 3000:3000 echo_app
```

End goal is to echo user input , like so :

```
http://example/?name=Eyal -> Hello Eyal
http://example/ -> Hello World
```

**ERROR IM GETTING**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:
 - /app/index.js
   .
   .
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/app/index.js' ]
}
```

Directroy containes :

- index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const log4js = require('log4js')

const app = express()
const logger = log4js.getLogger()

const echo = (req, res) => {
  logger.debug("Request: ", req)
  const input = 'name' in req.query ? req.query.input : ''
  if (input.length == 0) {
    res.send('Echo World')
  } else {
    res.send(`Echo ${input}`)
  }
}
app.get('/', (req, res) => echo(req, res))
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12
WORKDIR /app
ADD . ./
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/app/index.js"]
```

- package.json

```
{
  "name": "echo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "You talk, we talk back!",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "eyal",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "log4js": "^5.2.2",
    "saslprep": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it up and running, you first need to install the node dependencies by adding `npm install` to your Dockerfile, like this

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:12
WORKDIR /app
ADD . ./
RUN npm install
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "/app/index.js"]
```

Then you need to have your Node app listen for requests by adding

```
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:3000`)
  })
```

at the bottom of index.js.

Finally, a small error in your code. `req.query.input` needs to be `req.query.name`.

That should hopefully get you going.